# Meteor Text Search has no results?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, coffeescript

My webapp consists of just a list of topics and a search field to filter them with.

I started by inserting an object into my `MongoDB`:

```
$meteor mongo
meteor:PRIMARY> db.topics.insert({title:"Hello World!"});
```

I wrote this in my `.coffee` file to verify that it showed up as expected:

```
topics = new Mongo.Collection "topics"

if Meteor.isClient
    Template.body.helpers {
        topics: -> topics.find {}
    }
```

That worked fine. So I decided to move to having a fixed filter of `"Hello"`. I replaced `topics.find {}` with:

```
topics.find {$text: {$search: "Hello"}}
```

This caused my list to appear empty. I also tried this:

```
topics.find {title: {$text: {$search: "Hello"}}}
```

But that also did not work. What am I missing here?

(Also, this is my first time using `CoffeeScript`. The generated `JavaScript` file looked right to me, but if you see any unnecessary punctuation or other bad habits in here, please point it out to me. As someone who tends to help Python programmers, I know how obnoxious it is for people new to the language to be littering it with unnecessary semicolons.)

**Update**

I have added in the following server code as directed by [Blakes Seven in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31175391/901641):

```
if Meteor.isServer
    Meteor.startup -> topics._ensureIndex {title: "text"}
```

If I query the `MongoDB` from the command line as below, it works fine:

```
$meteor mongo
meteor:PRIMARY> db.topics.find({$text: {$search: "Hello"}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("559495cf7b8f68a693d8a3a8"), "title" : "Hello World!" }
```

However, within my application, in the client code, `topics.find {$text: {$search: "Hello"}}` is still not working.

**Update 2**

Blakes Seven wanted to see this:

```
$meteor mongo
meteor:PRIMARY> db.topics.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "meteor.topics"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "title_text",
        "ns" : "meteor.topics",
        "safe" : true,
        "weights" : {
            "title" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 2
    }
]
```

Comment: You need to create a [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/)

Comment: @BlakesSeven: Where exactly would I do that? Right after I assign `topics`? In `Meteor.startup`? Am I forced to do it from the `mongo` command line? Or is there someplace else I haven't considered yet that I should put it?

Comment: @BlakesSeven: I added the line `topics.createIndex {title: "text"}` to my `Meteor.startup`, but it crashes with a `TypeError`, saying that it `has no method 'createIndex'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a ["text index"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) on your collection before you can perform [**`$text`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) search queries.

You can create this index to deploy in `Meteor.startup` under `server/indexes` as:

```js
Meteor.startup(function() {

    topics._ensureIndex({ "title": "text" })

]);
```

MongoDB 3.x series recommends it's method [`.createIndex()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/), but the current meteor methods are like still calling [`.ensureIndex()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/) at present.

This isn't really that much of a concern as the preferred method has expanded sytax to support additional features mostly, and none of these should be a general concern.

If you find a need for those features, you can always script "index" deployment outside of your Meteor application code.

---

Just as a sidenote, it's a general convention to refer to a collection model both in the "singular" rather than "plural" form, as the collection itself is the "plural" and not the model. Also a general convention is a "capital" first.

Comment: Okay, I first tried making an index with one set of options, it didn't work, so I tried changing it. Now it gives me this: `MongoError: Index with pattern: ... already exists with different options`. How do I get rid of the old index?

Comment: On a side note, it's really irritating how docs.meteor.com doesn't talk about Collection indexes at all.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Actually it does. You need to change the "drop down" on the menu to the "Full API" option ( or whatever it is called, can't remember and not looking now ). However there is no note of the `._ensureIndex()` method there, or anything else with a `_` prefix.

Comment: Even with Full API, there's still not a single mention of indexes. Anyways, do you know how to get rid of the old index and replace it with the one I want?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare `._dropIndex()` shares the same argument options as [`.dropIndex()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/) in the core API

Comment: Thanks, but the code still isn't working. I had too much to say in a comment, so I updated my question above. Thanks again for the help so far!

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I hate coffeescript, hacky stuff. Please post a shell result from `db.topics.getIndicies()`

Comment: Added in an Update 2. Also, I think the name of the method is `getIndexes`, not `getIndicies` - I got a name error when I tried what you suggested but it recognized `getIndexes`, which I saw listed in the `MongoDB` documentation.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare The function call is the same. Your text search should be working. There is something else wrong in your code.

Comment: I'm now having a similar error, did this get resolved @ArtOfWarfare ?

Comment: @Vish - Probably not. I ended up giving up on meteor after a week of playing with it.